LineageOS 21.0 Build for SONY z3c
There are no new builds for SONY z3c since LineageOS 21, so I tried this manual meant for <18.1 in order to build a new version for z3c.
The breakfast-command leads to:
build/make/core/product_config.mk:226: error: Cannot locate config makefile for product "lineage_z3c".
18:58:49 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1
** Don't have a product spec for: 'lineage_z3c'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

Is there any hope to build a proper new lineageos for z3c?

Currently lineage-18.1 is the latest version that can be built for this device. To make a 20.1 or 21.1 build quite a lot of porting work would need to be done, and this is not an easy task.
One ray of hope is that there is a currently an unofficial 20.0 build for Z3 (not Z3 Compact). As Z3 and Z3C use very similar hardware, it is possible that this work could be used as the basis for a 20.0 build for Z3C. But that will only happen if there is someone with the time, motivation, and expertise to make it happen, and to do the necessary work
